# Chrome extension api chrome.sessions how to get session ID

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The chrome.sessions api specifies these three functions

```
getRecentlyClosed − chrome.sessions.getRecentlyClosed( Filter filter, function callback)
getDevices − chrome.sessions.getDevices( Filter filter, function callback)
restore − chrome.sessions.restore(string sessionId, function callback)
```

I see however no way to retrieve a sessionID to pass into the chrome.sessions.restore function.

How can I get the current sessions ID for restoring it somewhen in future?

Can I restore sessions indefinitely back in history respectively save a session?

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sessions#method-restore) says `The windows.Window.sessionId, or tabs.Tab.sessionId to restore. If this parameter is not specified, the most recently closed session is restored.`

Comment: Oh, i see! so i have to access it through the window.sessionId property. thanks!