# How can I get the sessionId in the chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to retrieve the sessionId in the chrome extension. The documentation says that the tab object should have the sessionId but it is not available for me. This is my code.

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(tab) {

       chrome.tabs.get(tab.tabId, function(tab){
              console.log(JSON.stringify(tab));
              });
 });
```

This is the log for a specific tab and it does not have a sessionId

```
{"active":true,"audible":false,"autoDiscardable":true,"discarded":false,"favIconUrl":"https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d","height":754,"highlighted":true,"id":113,"incognito":false,"index":14,"mutedInfo":{"muted":false},"pinned":false,"selected":true,"status":"complete","title":"Chrome extension api chrome.sessions how to get session ID - Stack Overflow","url":"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683057/chrome-extension-api-chrome-sessions-how-to-get-session-id","width":1536,"windowId":29}
```

Comment: The documentation says "obtained from the [sessions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sessions) API", not from `tabs` API.